# Python: a generator version of struct.unpack

Tags: python, memory-management, struct, unpack

Python's `struct.unpack` returns a tuple. Is there a way to yield the elements one by one without constructing the intermediate tuple?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You could use a `ctypes.Structure` to lazily create Python objects as you access them. Otherwise you'd need to write something yourself. Something like the following:

```
import struct
import re

re_split_fmt = re.compile("\s*[0-9]*\S", re.DOTALL)

def unpack_iter(fmt, buf):
    if fmt == "":
        return ()
    if fmt[0] in "<>=!":
        byteorder = fmt[0]
        fmt = fmt[1:]
    else:
        raise ValueError, "can't handle possibly padded formats"

    if "p" in fmt:
        raise ValueError, "can't handle pascal strings"

    def generator(i, buf, offset = 0):
        for m in i:
            fmt = byteorder + m.group(0)
            size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
            if fmt[-1] != 'x':
                s = buf[offset : offset + size]
                for a in struct.unpack(fmt, s):
                    yield a
            offset += size

    return generator(re_split_fmt.finditer(fmt), buf)
```